# Need assistance with inheritance logic

Tags: java, inheritance

If I have a subclass called AmericanFender which extends Fender, while Fender extends the superclass BassGuitars, why would something like

`AmericanFender amFen = new AmericanFender();
 System.out.println(amFen.brand);`

not work out to amFen.brand equaling "Fender" when

`Fender fen = new Fender()
fen.brand = Fender;`

Instead amFen.brand is coming out to be null. I thought since AmericanFender extends Fender, it inherits the instance variables of Fender(which those are inherited from BassGuitars) as long as they are public? I'm obviously thinking about inheritance incorrectly, so could someone steer me in the right direction? Much appreciated!

Comment: Why is AmericanFender its own class? I feel like that should just be an instance of a Fender with a type of "American"

Comment: It's just a little program I was playing with to get the hang of inheritance. That is probably the better thing to do.

Comment: Basically, I have a rule that I only create subclasses for extending or overriding functionality of parent classes. Any changeable "instance variables" don't necessitate a new class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In inheritance, `AmericanFender` DOES inherit the instance variables of `Fender`. This means it will have the same fields as `Fender`. This does NOT mean it will have the same values in these fields. It will have an empty field called brand, which is what you are seeing.

If you want it to inherit the value, you could make a method inside your `Fender` class:

```
public String getBrand() {
 return "Fender";
}
```

And then you can call:

```
AmericanFender f = new AmericanFender();
System.out.println(f.getBrand());
```

Comment: Oh awesome! Man I feel kind of silly, that's a relatively simple answer. Thank you for that, I understand now. I'll accept the answer when I'm able to.  Much appreciated!

Comment: @BobRoss No problem - happy to help.

Comment: It inherts the class fields (not instance variables) only if they're at least `protected`.

Answer (score 0):

If you could post a whole part of your code maybe the question would be more specific, however what you might have misunderstood about inheritance is that if a class inherits another class, then the subclass inherits the same fields from the super class but not the value inside the field. For example:

```
class kid extends parent {
```

if you have a field named haircolor in the parent class and

```
parent.haircolor = brown;
```

then the kid also has a haircolor characteristic but it doesn't equal *brown*. It equals *null* until you initialize it.